# Projecting feature locations onto D3.js geo projections

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to add some dots representing the locations of various features onto some of D3.js's geographic projections.  I would like the dots to rotate and get clipped the same as the country paths, but I'm having some difficulty getting this to work.

For a given projection, I can obtain the updated coordinates by updating the projection according to the drag as in the [demo](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/azimuthal.html), then calling projection() on the coordinates that I want to update, but this does not clip the circles correctly (you can see the circles on the opposite side of the globe).  Would it be possible to get an example of this?  To recap, I'd like to draw a circle around, say, New York city, then be able to rotate the globe and have the circle "set".

Thanks!

Lauren

Comment: So what was the solution to this problem, would be really helpful if you could share it with us :)